# Is it Forbidden to Stream YouTube Video on Background?

Tags: android, audio, background, stream, youtube

I would like to create an application for Android that uses the media player to stream a video from YouTube on background (using the rtsp link delivered from mobile version).

I found out that the [YouTube Music and Audio Player](http://pt.appbrain.com/app/youtube-music-audio-player/rd.youaud) has been removed from Google Play, and I want to know:

- Do Google policies forbid streams from YouTube on background?
- Will Google remove my application because it streams YouTube video on background?

Comment: Hi, have you found answers for your questions?

Comment: Not yet Wayne. But, there are some apps with the same purpose:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.asbit.pvstar
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tw.com.freedi.youtube.player
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thepandasteam.playtubedemo

Comment: Check this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mthli/Ninja/master/Art/info/reject.png http://prntscr.com/gaq7j4